# How to add mp3 file in modern SharePoint site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages

I need to add an audio (mp3) file in the modern SharePoint site. I found information that I can do that by using embed code:

`<iframe src="pathtomyaudiofile.mp3" width="100%" height="100"></iframe >`

However, when I add it, the audio starts playing automatically each time when I open the SP site.

Is there an option to add paused audio, so anyone who wishes to listen to it will have to click 'play'?

Answer (score 0):

I've done some testing and audio in an iframe or a video-element doesn't seem to autoplay for me.

You could though, try to replace your iframe with a video-element:

```
<video width="100" height="100" controls muted>
  <source src="pathtomyaudiofile.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</video>
```

OR using an audio-element

```
<audio src="pathtomyaudiofile.mp3" controls muted />
```

This should not autoplay and if it does, it will be muted.

Comment: Thank you @DmitriyVdE 

Could you advise how should I add a video or audio element? When I try to add them I get an error message saying that embed code must be iframe-based.

Comment: @Julia You could try to put either option inside of an <iframe></iframe>-element.